# Array Shifting / Wrong Index / i = [x+y*size+z*size*size]

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

I have a simple question. How can I shift a linear array in 3 dimensions?​
It seems too work but in the X & Y axis i got an index problem.
The reson why I wanna do this is simple. I want to create a volumetric terrain with a chunk buffer, so i only have to recalulate values on the edges when the viewport is moving.

I have read an article about this system :

> Essentially they provide a way to scroll a potentially infinite data
>   field through a fixed size multi-resolution cache.

So my pipline for the generation part would be:

1. When viewport moves get axis
2. Shift the axis
3. Generate some noise only for the new cells
4. Triangulate the new cells
5. Update all cell positions

[image]

Here are my other images:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/array-shifting-wrong-index-i-x-y-size-z-size-size.425448/#post-2751774

**Nobody in the unity forums could answer my question...**

```
public int size;
public float speed;

private byte[] volume;
private byte[] shifted;

public bool widthShift, heightShift, depthShift;

private int widthOffset = 0;
private int heightOffset = 0;
private int depthOffset = 0;

private float time = 0;
private int cube;

void Start()
{
    volume = new byte[size * size * size];
    shifted = new byte[size * size * size];

    cube = size * size * size;

    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                volume[x + y * size + z * size * size] = (x == 0 || y == 0 || z == 0) ? (byte)1 : (byte)0;
}

void Update()
{
    time += Time.fixedDeltaTime * speed;

    if (time > 1)
    {
        time = 0;

        widthOffset = (widthOffset >= size) ? 0 : widthOffset;
        heightOffset = (heightOffset >= size) ? 0 : heightOffset;
        depthOffset = (depthOffset >= size) ? 0 : depthOffset;

        if (widthShift)
            widthOffset++;
        else
            widthOffset = 0;

        if (heightShift)
            heightOffset++;
        else
            heightOffset = 0;

        if (depthShift)
            depthOffset++;
        else
            depthOffset = 0;

        Shift(widthOffset, heightOffset, depthOffset);
    }
}

void Shift(int xOff, int yOff, int zOff)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < size; z++)
            {
                int i = ((x + xOff) + (y + yOff) * size + (z + zOff) * size * size);
                i = (i >= cube) ? (i - cube) : i;

                shifted[x + y * size + z * size * size] = volume[i];
            }
}

void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    if(Application.isPlaying)
        for(int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < size; y++)
                for(int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    Gizmos.color = (shifted[x + y * size + z * size * size] == 1) ? new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255) : new Color32(255, 0, 0, 4);
                    Gizmos.DrawWireCube(new Vector3(x + 0.5f, y + 0.5f, z + 0.5f), new Vector3(0.95f, 0.95f, 0.95f));
                }
}
```

Comment: I gotta say, for a new user, this question was really well formatted and asked. Not something I see too often when going through the review queues. :) Welcome to stack overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
void Shift(int xOff, int yOff, int zOff)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            for(int z = 0; z < size; z++)
            {
                int nx = (x + xOff) % size;
                int ny = (y + yOff) % size;
                int nz = (z + zOff) % size;
                int i = (nx + ny * size + nz * size * size);

                shifted[x + y * size + z * size * size] = volume[i];
            }
}
```